# Django Authentication error

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am quite new in django.I would like to authenticate a user. But I am unable to do it using authenticate function. I have looked over authenticate function in django. and there it's always showing TypeError. I have used both unicode and string in separate time but always it's showing the TypeError. 
Please any help will be appreciated. 
I am attching my code below:

```
def loginTest(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return HomePage(request)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')


def login(request):
    return render_to_response('login.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def HomePage(req):
    templ = get_template('HomePage.html')
    variables = Context({})
    output = templ.render(variables)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're defining a "login" view yourself, so when you try to call `login(request, user)` (what I assume is Django's built in "login" function which sets the user session), it is instead calling your function:

```
def login(request):
    return render_to_response('login.html',{},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Second, where did the TypeError occur? I assume since you know the nature of the error you've gotten to the Django traceback error page, if you could post the "copy-and-paste view" of the traceback itself, that would be enormously helpful.

You're also doing some funky things with your views that can be easily cleaned up by some shortcut functions. :)

However, since the nature of your question is how to do authentication in Django, here is the base you need to implement a manual login process, mostly just taken from the [relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in):

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

def loginTest(request):
    username = request.POST["username"]
    password = request.POST["password"]
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            HttpResponseRedirect("/login/")

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def HomePage(request):
    return render(request, "HomePage.html")
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'authtest.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^login/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^', 'custom.views.HomePage'),
)
```

Also, for future reference, it would be helpful for you to post your entire script so we can see what you have imported at the top.